# Travel To France from UK via Eurotunnel after June 9th

Tags: france, uk-citizens, vaccinations, eurotunnel, covid-19

UK citizens (ourselves included) will be looking to use the Eurotunnel after June 9th when France says it will allow open travel. Will the NHS App (with vaccination status) allow entry to France without a PCR test? Will the self quarantine rule be lifted after June 9th?

Comment: Who said France will open for travel on June 9th? I don't think any firm commitment or specific plan has been announced.

Comment: Found [some mention of the June 9th](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/A14896) date on an official site but it is still short on details.

Comment: At present it is still to early to say for sure. Based on present reports, efforts will be made to insure that the different forms of verification  of the vacination status (*NHS App* --> *Pass Sanitaire*, *TousAntiCovid*) will be interchangeable. The final details have not yet been made public on how this is to work. A further uncertainty *may* be caused by the Indian variant B1617.2.

Comment: [2021-04-29: Covid-19: President Macron gives four dates for easing of restrictions](https://www.connexionfrance.com/French-news/Covid-19-President-Macron-gives-four-dates-for-easing-of-restrictions)

Comment: I voted to reopen, the question is clear, objective and useful. Obviously information does not appear to be available right now but it should be easy to answer in a week or two, which goes to show that there is nothing wrong with it *per se*.